# Como colocar isso num ciclo for?

Tags: c#

código:

```cs
if (label1.Text != string.Empty && label2.Text != string.Empty && label3.Text != string.Empty && label4.Text != string.Empty && label5.Text != string.Empty && label6.Text != string.Empty && label7.Text != string.Empty && label8.Text != string.Empty && label9.Text != string.Empty)
{
    empate();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: a comparação é feita errada ... e se você tem uma sequencia pode ser feita um ciclo realmente pegando as label por algum quesito, pelos controles desse formulário ... acho que é Windows Forms ou é WebForms?

Comment: É windows forms. Comparação feita errada?

Answer (score 5):

Não ficou muito claro o que pretende, mas se for para substituir essa linha longa por um ciclo `for`, pode fazer assim:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
{
    if (this.Controls["label" + i].Text != string.Empty) count++;
}

if (count == 9)
{
    empate();
    return true;
}
```

Outra opção seria usar um container, por exemplo um `panel`, com as 9 `labels` lá dentro, e fazer:

```
if (this.panel1.Controls.Cast<Label>().Count(lbl => lbl.Text != string.Empty) == 9)
{
    empate();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: É exatamente isso, obrigado

Comment: @GonçaloSousa editei a resposta com outra opção.